# How to check what wallet the CLI is using?

Tags: solana-cli

Is there a quick and easy way to see the public key of the account that is being used by solana cli?

For example, I know it's possible to `cat` the file `~/.config/solana/cli/config.yml` and `cat` and see

```
json_rpc_url: "https://api.mainnet-beta.solana.com"
websocket_url: ""
keypair_path: /root/.config/solana/id.json
address_labels:
  "11111111111111111111111111111111": System Program
commitment: confirmed
```

but does the cli have a way of showing what is the public key of `id.json` (or whatever keypair you happen to have in the config file)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is easily done with `solana address`. You can always change the id the CLI is using with `solana config set -k <path_to_another_json>`

Comment: yeh, it is super simple. Figured it out just after asking by just running `solana -help` and seeing what commands were available

Answer (score 1):

You can also go to your json file directly: `/root/.config/solana/id.json` and import via a private key in Phantom everything you have in the json file. This will allow you to have the wallet on Phantom and to be able to make transactions, see the activities etc.. more easily

Comment: uploading the private key to phantom just to get the public key isn't really quick and/or easy though, and it doesn't use the CLI. But for sure, I've definitely done this in the past

Answer (score 1):

And yet one more option using a lighter command, you can just do `solana-keygen pubkey`